# Enabling/Disabling Conditions WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.5, conditional-statements, wix3.6

Having an issue with a multiple condition statement such as:

```
<Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[(WCF_USE_PROXY = 1 AND WCF_PROXY_URL <> "" AND WCF_PROXY_USERNAME <> "" AND WCF_PROXY_USERNAME <> "")OR WCF_USE_PROXY <> 1]]></Condition>
<Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[WCF_USE_PROXY = 1 AND(ACTIVATIONPASSWORD = "" OR ACTIVATIONSERVICEURL = "" OR BASEADDRESSURL = "")]]></Condition>-->
```

For some reason if all my text boxes aren't empty it still doesn't enable, can someone point me at the probably easy fix!

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer evaluates control conditions when another control takes focus. So if you are modifying an edit box value, that modification will update control conditions only after selecting another control.

Control conditions are not updated dynamically as you type.

Comment: Even when I click on another control, I don't get the box enabling. I think it's the conditions themselves that are wrong. If I have brackets it doesn't seem to work: e.g (X and Y) OR Z